# Is this an inefficient query?

Tags: mysql

Assuming table1 and table2 both have a large number of rows (ie several hundred thousand), is the following an inefficient query?

Edit: Order by field added.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT title, updated FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT title, updated FROM table2
) AS query
ORDER BY updated DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely need distinct results, another possibility is to use `union all` and a `group by` clause instead:

```
SELECT title FROM (
  SELECT title FROM table1 group by title
  UNION ALL
  SELECT title FROM table2 group by title
) AS query
group by title
LIMIT 25;
```

Testing this without the `limit` clause on an indexed ID column from two tables with ~920K rows each in a test database (at `$work`) resulted in a bit over a second with the query above and about 17 seconds via a `union`.

Comment: EXPLAIN shows that this query also needs to examine all the rows

Comment: @Esailija - Yes it does, but if distinct results are needed, then I'm not sure how you can get away with not examining all of the rows. I've added `group by` clauses for each of the queries being put together via `union all`, but for really huge tables, that may not make that much of a difference.

Comment: With group by you still need to examine all the rows. union vs union all doesn't matter at all in terms of performance if you only examine 25 rows, since it's such a tiny dataset. You can do that with order by and limit but that's already in my answer

Comment: Databases perform reasonably well. Computers are fast. Unless you need to perform this query multiple times per second (and if you do, then you may need a NoSQL solution), then it probably isn't worth the time to futz over a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

this should be even faster - but then I see no ORDER BY so what 25 records do you actually want?

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT title FROM table1 LIMIT 25
  UNION
  SELECT title FROM table2 LIMIT 25
) AS query
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Shouldn't the inner queries be `LIMIT 12.5`?

Comment: How do you fetch half of a row?

Comment: the main goal is not to go through all 200,000 - it could be 12.5 (funny number) - hence the order by question...

Comment: @JackManey, simple.  You pull out the network cable at *just the right moment*.

Comment: Actually, with the `UNION` there's no guarantee the inner query will return 25 rows (or even 12.5 :) because any duplicates are suppressed. If the 25 rows can include dups then I'd suggest `SELECT title FROM table1 LIMIT 25 UNION ALL SELECT title FROM table2 LIMIT 25` for the inner query. If dups aren't wanted would `SELECT DISTINCT title FROM table1 LIMIT 25 UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT title FROM table2 LIMIT 25` work? Just throwing these out there for discussion; I don't know about the performance implications off the top of my head.

Comment: EXPLAIN shows that this query also needs to examine all the rows

Comment: You seem to be surprised by that Esailija - I don't need to look at the explain plan to tell that. But one would very rarely **ever** see a query like this in an application - there's always some basis for filtering it, and you should never use a LIMIT clause without an explicit sort (which is another reason why the inner SELECTs should be limited to 25 rows).

Comment: @symcbean but the poster obviously does. If he didn't, why would he post it since it's just as slow as what the OP currently has?

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` must make an extra pass to fetch the `distinct` records, so you should use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I would suggest to limit the inner queries to 25 as well.

Comment: I wouldn't because we don't know what kind of data should be `LIMIT`ed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use order by and limits in the inner queries.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT title FROM table1 ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT C)
  UNION
  (SELECT title FROM table2 ORDER BY title ASC LIMIT C)
) AS query
LIMIT 25
```

This will only go through C rows instead of N (hundreds of thousands). The ORDER BY is necessary and should be on an indexed column.

C is a heuristic constant that should be tuned according to the domain. If you only expect a few duplicates, C=50-100 is probably ok.

You can also find out this for yourself by using EXPLAIN.

Comment: This query might not retrieve 25 distinct results.

Comment: @JackManey You can increase the inner limits so that it does, for example use `1000`. That's still much better than examining 100k's of rows.

Comment: Determining the amount by which the inner `limit`s should be increased to guarantee 25 distinct results would probably require some knowledge about the distribution of the `title` column in each of `table1` and `table2`.

Comment: @JackManey Yeah, you can tune it according to the domain. 1000 is probably a huge overkill when it comes to 100k's of titles anyway, don't you think?

Comment: @JackManey Sorry to bugger you again :) I see you have some solid background on these type of issues. I
can't see why taking a few minutes to think about the nature of the data one is storing is
not worth a performance improvement of a few orders of magnitude. Can you explain that?

Comment: Again, it depends on the distribution of the `title` column and in what order they're loaded (the second part we have no control over without using an `order by` clause). If there are less than 25 distinct values of `title` in the `2*C` rows that you pulled up in the subquery, then you'll end up with less than 25 rows. Truth be told, if these tables only have a few hundred thousand rows each, then scanning all of the rows (especially on an indexed column) is not that much of a strain on the database.